# Ruby on Rails: Nested Model Form Checkbox For A 'has_many :through' Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through, form-for, fields-for

Still fairly new to RoR, let alone Ruby itself.
Here's my issue. I'm using Rails 4 and Ruby 2.1.0

I have a User class with this relationship:

```
has_many :roles, ->{ uniq }, :through => :user_roles
accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles
```

Now, the table 'roles' simply has a list of roles, such as 'admin', 'moderator', 'visitor', 'artist', etc.

The table 'user_roles', is just a relational table, with the role's key and the user's key.

So, to clarify, 'users' has a one to many relationship with 'user_roles' and "user_roles' table has a many to one relationship with the 'roles' table.

Something like this:

```
users: id, name, email #ie: 12, 'mikey', 'mike@foobar.com'
user_roles: id, user_id, role_id #ie: 4324, 12, 8
roles: id, name, weight #ie: 8, 'moderator', 11
```

I've been given the task of adding a checkbox toggle in the admin section so that an admin can grant the moderator role to any one user.

Each admin page is for one specific user. Therefore, the form_for is based on the @user instance, depending on which user the admin selected for editing.

RailsCasts #196 kind of helped me understand the concept, but it's platform is just different enough that I'm not sure how to exactly translate it into what I need. Likewise, there are some similar questions here on StackOverflow as well - but again, I can't seem to get it to translate correctly into my situation.

What I do have, I think should be at least somewhere in the realm of the right direction. THen again, maybe I'm way off. Here is my form code:

```
= form_for @user, :url => admin_user_path(@user), html:{class: 'form_horizontal'} do |f|
  %br
  %h4{class: :dc_green}Logistical Information
  = f.label :display_name, "Display Name"
  = f.text_field :display_name
  = f.label :email, "eMail"
  = f.text_field :email
  %br

  = f.fields_for :roles do |a|
    = a.check_box :moderator, { inline_label: :none }
    = a.label :moderator, {for: :moderator, class: "checkbox inline"}
    %br
```

The error I'm getting with this form code is: undefined method `moderator'

Thank you in advance for anyone who can offer support :)

I guess I should probably add that I'm also clueless as to how I should handle this in the controller once it is submitted. But, first things first.

UPDATE
So, the reason I'm getting the undefined error is because it doesn't exist for that user. Which is bad. I need to be able to add the role to the user or remove the role. However, the only roles coming through are the roles the user has already been assigned to. So I'm totally doing this wrong. Now I'm really in the dark.

Comment: This code doesn't include `author`. Is the stack trace pointing to your controller? Can we see that code?

Comment: What's `author`, an attribute from a model, a method defined somewhere? Please explain a little bit more

Comment: or, I'm sorry - that's a different role type I was just testing out. If I use moderator, it will say the same thing. Undefined method `moderator'